# Likelihood Function and Maximum Likelihood Estimator for Random Variable dependent on another Geometrically Distributed Random Variable

Tags: probability, distributions, maximum-likelihood

Let $T_j$ be the year employee $j$ quits a job and it follows a geometric distribution with parameter $\theta$ such that
$$
P(T_j=t)=\theta(1-\theta)^{t-1}
$$
From a sample of $m$ employees, the number who quit in year $t$ for $t=1,2,...,7$ is observed and called this $Z_t$. The number of employees who remain in the role past 7 years is also observed and called $Y_8=n-\sum_{i=1}^7Y_t$.

Given $Y_1, Y_2,...,Y_8$, I need to find the likelihood function for $\theta$, maximum likelihood estimate for $\theta$, and the standard error for the maximum likelihood estimate for $\theta$. I thought I did the first 2 things, but I realized afterward I didn't use the the $Y_t$ values and I am unsure of how to incorporate them.

I currently do the following for the likelihood
$$
\begin{align*}
L(\theta)&=\left[\prod_{t=1}^7\theta(1-\theta)^{t-1}\right]\left[1-\sum_{t=1}^7\theta(1-\theta)^{t-1}\right] \\
&=\theta^7(1-\theta)^{\sum_{t=1}^7(t-1)}\left[1-\sum_{t=1}^7\theta(1-\theta)^{t-1}\right] \\
&=\theta^7(1-\theta)^{21}\left[1-\sum_{t=1}^7\theta(1-\theta)^{t-1}\right] \\
&=\theta^7(1-\theta)^{21}-\theta^7(1-\theta)^{21}\left[\sum_{t=1}^7\theta(1-\theta)^{t-1}\right] \\
&=\theta^7(1-\theta)^{21}-\theta^8\left[\sum_{t=1}^7(1-\theta)^{t+20}\right] 
\end{align*}
$$

I then take the log of this likelihood function
$$
\begin{align*}
\ln\left[L(\theta)\right]&=\ln\left(\theta^7(1-\theta)^{21}-\theta^8\left[\sum_{t=1}^7(1-\theta)^{t+20}\right] \right) \\
&=\ln\left[\theta^7(1-\theta)^{21}\right]-\ln\left(\theta^8\left[\sum_{t=1}^7(1-\theta)^{t+20}\right]\right) \\
&=\ln\left[\theta^7\right]+\ln\left[(1-\theta)^{21}\right]-\ln\left[\theta^8\right]-\sum_{t=1}^7\ln\left[(1-\theta)^{t+20}\right] \\
&=7\ln\left[\theta\right]+21\ln(1-\theta)-8\ln\left[\theta\right]-\sum_{t=1}^7(t+20)\ln[1-\theta] \\
&=\left[21-\sum_{t=1}^7(t+20)\right]\ln(1-\theta)-\ln\left[\theta\right] \\
&=\left[21-168\right]\ln(1-\theta)-\ln\left[\theta\right] \\
&=-147\ln(1-\theta)-\ln\left[\theta\right]
\end{align*}
$$
Taking the derivative with respect to $\theta$
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{d\theta}\ln\left[L(\theta)\right]&=\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(-147\ln(1-\theta)-\ln\left[\theta\right]\right) \\
&=-147\frac{d}{d\theta}\ln(1-\theta)-\frac{d}{d\theta}\ln\left[\theta\right] \\
&=-147\left(\frac{1}{\theta-1}\right)-\frac{1}{\theta} \\
&=-\frac{147}{\theta-1}-\frac{1}{\theta}
\end{align*}
$$
Setting the derivative equal to 0 and solving for $\theta$
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{d\theta}\ln\left[L(\theta)\right]=-\frac{147}{\theta-1}-\frac{1}{\theta}&=0 \\
-\frac{147(\theta-1)}{\theta-1}-\frac{\theta-1}{\theta}&=0 \\
-147-1+\frac{1}{\theta}&=0 \\
-148+\frac{1}{\theta}&=0 \\
\frac{1}{\theta}&=148 \\
\theta&=\frac{1}{148}
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start out with the log of the likelihood function for a single individual who quit in year $t$:

$$\mathcal{L}(\theta) = \log \theta + (t-1)\log (1-\theta)$$

If I have $Y_t$ such individuals, the log likelihood is the sum of the log likelihoods for each individual, which, since $Y_t$ represents the number of individuals who quit in year $t$, is just $Y_t$ times the log likelihood for a single individual who quit in year $t$:

$$\mathcal{L}(\theta; Y_t) = Y_t\log \theta + Y_t(t-1)\log (1-\theta)$$

And summing over the seven observed values of $Y_t$ gives us:

$$\mathcal{L}(\theta; Y) = \sum_{t=1}^7 [Y_t\log \theta + Y_t(t-1)\log (1-\theta)]$$

Adding in the term corresponding to the individuals who lasted longer than seven years:

$$\mathcal{L}(\theta; Y) = \sum_{t=1}^7 [Y_t\log \theta + Y_t(t-1)\log (1-\theta)] + Y_8\log[1-\sum_{i=1}^7\theta(1-\theta)^{i-1}]$$

Dealing with the last term on the r.h.s. does not look as easy as we might like, but we can make use of an interesting relationship:

$$1-\sum_{i=0}^k\theta(1-\theta)^k = (1-\theta)^{k+1}$$

Substituting while being careful with the index of summation gives:

$$\mathcal{L}(\theta; Y) = \sum_{t=1}^7 [Y_t\log \theta + Y_t(t-1)\log (1-\theta)] + 7Y_8\log(1-\theta)$$

and some further rearranging of terms gets us to:

$$\mathcal{L}(\theta; Y) = \left(\sum_{t=1}^7 Y_t\right)\log \theta + \left(\sum_{t=1}^7tY_{t+1}\right)\log(1-\theta)$$

Simplifying our notation by defining $S_1 = \sum_{t=1}^7 Y_t$ and $S_2 = \sum_{t=1}^7tY_{t+1}$ sets us up nicely for minimizing our typing / writing while taking the derivatives:
$$\mathcal{L}(\theta; Y) = S_1\log \theta + S_2\log(1-\theta)$$

... at which point you should be able to take over!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @jbowman! If you don't mind, would you have any  idea of how to go about finding an estimate of the standard error of the MLE? I was thinking to outright take the variance of it, summing the sample variances involved in the sums, but that seems to involved a lot of unknowns. Also, on a minor formatting note, would the probability of having Y_t people quit be written $P(Y_t=Y_t)$? Sorry for the hassle and thank you again for your time and help!

Comment: The latter would be $P(Y_t = y_t)$; the former you would typically do using the second derivative of the log likelihood (Fisher information) and plugging your estimates into the resulting equation (see Cramer-Rao lower bound for the theory.)  I'll try to remember to add that derivation to the answer tomorrow...